# Implementing Socket.io in Angular service

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket, socket.io

I would use socket.IO in my angular application , specially in my service.

I've implemented the `emit` function in my back end already.

Here is my angular logique.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { NouveauProjet } from "./models/nouveau-projet";
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/catch";
import * as io from "socket.io-client";


@Injectable()
export class AjoutprojService {
  socket = io('http://localhost:8081');
  apiURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/proj/projets";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient ) {};
  this.socket.on('added', function (){

    getAllProj(): Observable<NouveauProjet[]> {
      return this.http.get<NouveauProjet[]>(
        "http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/proj/projets"
      );
    }
  });
  getProj(id): Observable<NouveauProjet[]> {
    return this.http.get<NouveauProjet[]>(
      "http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/proj/nouvProjs/" + id
    );
  }
  addProj(nouveauProjet: NouveauProjet): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<NouveauProjet[]>(
      "http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/proj/projets",
      nouveauProjet
    );

  }
}
```

I get this error :

```
ERROR in ./src/app/ajoutproj.service.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (42:31)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| this.socket.on('added', function () {
|     getAllProj();
|     Observable < NouveauProjet[] > {
|         return: this.http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/proj/projets")
|     };
```

Same error when I use it in my component.